# Failed to update dynamic user credentials: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character

Tags: systemd

When starting a systemd service with `DynamicUser=true` I get the error message "Failed to update dynamic user credentials: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character".

Answer (score 0):

**Disable DynamicUser**:

```
DynamicUser=false
```

This happens when the user name selected by systemd already exists on the system. This can be either because of an explicit `User` setting in the service file or an automatically deduced username based on the service name.

The simplest solution is to unset `DynamicUser` so that the existing user account is used. Otherwise, explicitly change the username by setting the `User` option in the service file.

The `Group` name might need to be specified too, if it also exists — the group name defaults to the user name if unset.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for getting this error is kernel configuration missing CONFIG_FILE_LOCKING.

Yet another reason: related to running in a container. Details here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9493